# SQL Cast Date as DDMMMYYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, casting

I was previously using:

```
Left(replace(cast(TICKET_EXPIRATION_DATE as varchar(10)), ''-'', ''''),9)
```

But I need to change the format of the date to be DDMMMYYYY. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Hover your cursor over the `SQL` tag you chose for your question and read about the different DBMS that exist *(with very different syntax for DATEs)* and then please let us know if it's MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc, etc.

Comment: which database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server, and that your original datatype is one of the DATE datatypes...

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), TICKET_EXPIRATION_DATE, 106), ' ', '')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0f5b0/7